# Rename file in directory it is found

Tags: macos, bash, bash-scripting, applescript

I want to find all files that end in file.one.ext and rename them to file.ext

I have managed to get this far, however it then moves the file to the working directory, not the directory it found the file in.

```
find . -name "file.one.ext" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "file.ext"' {} \;
```

$0 contains the full path and filename, yet how do I get that directory to attach it to the new file name.

I also have `rename` installed, if that makes things easier. I am on a macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How do I rename a file in directory it's in?

All you are missing is [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) from the command:

```
find . -name "file.one.ext" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "$(dirname $0)/file.ext"' {} \;
```

### Example

```
mkdir test1 test2
touch test1/file.one.ext test2/file.one.ext
find . -name "file.one.ext" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "$(dirname $0)/file.ext"' {} \;
ls test1/ test2/

test1/:
file.ext

test2/:
file.ext
```

### Demo

[image: animated gif of example output]